# How to phrase MySQL query to return latest entry for a particular user based on a value

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a nasty query that I need to run; but I just can't think of how to do it.

So I have a table called:

```
playtime
```

With columns for:

```
playtime_id -> auto-incrementing
date -> date of entry
player_name
join_or_leave -> possible values are 'join' or 'leave'
```

What I need to get in the query is the latest entry for every user (player_name) where 'join_or_leave' is equal to 'join', but only if the latest entry for that user is 'join'. So if the most recent value for a user is 'leave', it ignores that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self join will get you only results of max `date`. And with the additional `where` clause the join will only succeed if the max date record also has a 'join' in `join_or_leave`.

```
select p1.player_name
from playtime p1
inner join 
(
  select player_name, max(date) as mdate
  from playtime
  group by player_name
)
p2 on p1.player_name = p2.player_name and p1.date = p2.mdate 
where p1.join_or_leave = 'join'
```

Comment: Just tried using this, but I'm getting 'Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in...' when using $stmt->execute().

Comment: I was missing the `from` key word. Please try again. I updated the query.

Comment: The query now works, thanks! I was going along completely the wrong lines. :p

Comment: I am sure there is not just one way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

OK just add a timestamp column to your table and compare according to the timestamp. The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM playtime WHERE join_or_leave = join ORDER BY timestamp
```

then parse the results in scripting language you are using to get the latest entry in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just aggregation and a trick in MySQL:

```
select player_name
from playtime
group by player_name
having substring_index(group_concat(join_or_leave order by date desc), ',', 1) = 'join'
```

That is, concatenate the `join_or_leave` values together in a list, ordered by `date` descending (for each `player_name`).  Then just choose the ones where this is `join`.